# Error on "-e" parameter when running makecert command in powershell

Tags: powershell, certificate, sdk

I am trying to run the following command in Powershell on a machine running Server 2012:

```
makecert -r -pe -n CN="*.$domainVariable" -b 01/01/2000 -e 01/01/2036 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ss my -sr localmachine
```

I am getting the error:

```
makecert : The term 'makecert' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ makecert -r -pe -n CN="*.$domainVariable" -b 01/01/2000 -e 01/01/2036 -eku 1.3.6 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (makecert:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

So I ran this command after doing some research online:

```
set-location 'C:\Program Files\QACloneAutomation' makecert -r -pe -n CN="*.$domainVariable" -b 01/01/2000 -e 01/01/2036 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ss my -sr localmachine
```

Now I am getting this error:

```
Set-Location : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'e' is ambiguous. Possible matches include:
-ErrorAction -ErrorVariable.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\cloneSetup.ps1:48 char:107
+ ...  -b 01/01/2000 -e 01/01/2036 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ss my -sr localmachine
+                    ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameter,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

I am wondering if anyone knows of a resolution to this issue.  I saw one person submitted a ticket to Microsoft Connect about 8 years ago for the same issue (ticket # 183738), but I wasn't able to access Connect to find out what the result was.

Comment: Are you sure you actually have a utility named makecert?  Also, why are you trying to precede makecert with Set-Location?  That really doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I have the makecert.exe file in the folder I'm trying to execute it from.  Is there something else I need to get it going?

Comment: That worked!  Thank you!  I changed my command to this:
.\makecert.exe -r -pe -n CN="*.$domainVariable" -b 01/01/2000 -e 01/01/2036 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ss my -sr localmachine

Comment: Ok, I have added that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to Powershell you really need to give the full name of your non-powershell commands.  So instead of `makecert`, you should use `makecert.exe`.